# How to send Time and Date value from Postman to my REST API

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postman

I have a Schedules class as a Table in postgres with jamMulai, jamSelesai variable with a LocalTime data type, and tglTayang variable with a LocalDate variable

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "schedules")
public class Schedules implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long scheduleId;


    @Column(name = "tgl_tayang",columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate tglTayang;


    @Column(name = "jam_mulai",columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime jamMulai;


    @Column(name = "jam_selesai" ,columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime jamSelesai;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "film_id")
    private Films filmId;
```

This is my service method for the Schedules class

```
@Override
    public void saveSchedule(String jamMulai, String jamSelesai, String tglTayang, Long filmId) {
        Schedules schedules = new Schedules();
        schedules.setJamMulai(LocalTime.parse(jamMulai));
        schedules.setJamSelesai(LocalTime.parse(jamSelesai));
        schedules.setTglTayang(LocalDate.parse(tglTayang));
        Films films = filmsService.findFilmById(filmId);
        schedules.setFilmId(films);
        schedulesRepository.save(schedules);

    }
```

and this is my controller method

```
@PostMapping("/admin/add-schedule")
    public String addSchedule(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> schedule) {
        schedulesService.saveSchedule((String) schedule.get("jamMulai"), (String) schedule.get("jamSelesai"), (String) schedule.get("tglTayang"), (Long) schedule.get("filmId"));
        return "Add Films Success!";
    }
```

in the Postgres database the data type for jamMulai, jamSelesai, and tglTayang is time without time zone and date.

But when I try to request Post using Postman

```
{   
    "jamMulai":"20:00:00",
    "jamSelesai":"23:00:00",
    "tglTayang":"2020-05-12",
    "filmId":2
}
```

I get

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-17T13:41:52.771+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/cinema/schedules/admin/add-schedule"
}
```

I've tried changing the data type in Schedules class to a different time and date but it still doesn't work.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

ps: I know there's a similar question to this, but it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: then there should be a entry in your server log with the details

Comment: What is this 500 about? Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: @SveKamenska the error is 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Ronin7, I can see that :) I mean, the actual error which you can find in your backend logs

Comment: Now it can be anything, it even does not necesseraly related to the date issue. The time you see in the response - is just the default format of showing server-error, it shows time when error happened

Answer (score 0):

You said:
in the Postgres database the data type for jamMulai, jamSelesai, and **tglTayang** is **time** without time zone and date.

Why do you define:

```
@Column(name = "tgl_tayang",columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate tglTayang;
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
@Column(name = "tgl_tayang",columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime tglTayang;
```

?

Comment: my bad, data type for tglTayang is date. My phrasing is a bit wrong